# MVVM data binding issue, source property not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

I am currently working with the Microsoft MVVM template and trying to solve issue of logging into desktop shopping application. The problem is that text typed in view layer is not propagated to the source property MemberName.

My model:

```
public class Member : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    
    private int id;
    private string memberName;
    private string memberPass;
    
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
        
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }

        set
        {
            if (id == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id"));
        }
    }

    public string MemberName
    {
        get { return memberName; }

        set
        {
            if (memberName == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            memberName = value;

            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            bool valid = true;
            if (value == null || value == "")
            {
                errors.Add("MemberName cannot be empty.");
                SetErrors("MemberName", errors);
                valid = false;
            }
            if (!Regex.Match(value, @"^[a-zA-Z_0-9]+$").Success)
            {
                errors.Add("MemberName can only contain letters, numbers and underscore.");
                SetErrors("MemberName", errors);
                valid = false;
            }
            if (valid)
            {
                ClearErrors("MemberName");
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MemberName"));
        }
    }

    public string MemberPass
    {
        get { return memberPass; }

        set
        {
            if (memberPass == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            memberPass = value;

            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            bool valid = true;
            if (value == null || value == "")
            {
                errors.Add("Password cannot be empty.");
                SetErrors("MemberPass", errors);
                valid = false;
            }
            if (!Regex.Match(value, @"^[a-zA-Z_0-9]+$").Success)
            {
                errors.Add("Password can only contain letters, numbers and underscore.");
                SetErrors("MemberPass", errors);
                valid = false;
            }
            if (valid)
            {
                ClearErrors("MemberPass");
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MemberPass"));
        }
    }

    

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return (errors.Count > 0);
        }
    }

    public Member()
    {
        memberName = "";
        memberPass = "";
    }

    public string GetPassword(string memberName) {

        string Password = "default";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT MemberPass from Members where MemberName=@memberName", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberName", memberName);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Password = (string) reader["MemberPass"];
            }
        }
        }
        
        return Password;
    }
            

    private void SetErrors(string propertyName, List<string> propertyErrors)
    {
        
        errors.Remove(propertyName);
        
        errors.Add(propertyName, propertyErrors);
        
        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    
    private void ClearErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        
        errors.Remove(propertyName);
        
        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            return (errors.Values);
        }
        else
        {
            if (errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                return (errors[propertyName]);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View model is as following;

```
public class LogInViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Member logMember;
    
    public Member LogMember
    {
        get { return logMember; }
        set
        {
            if (logMember == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            logMember = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LogMember"));
        }
    }

    public LogInViewModel()
    {
        LogMember = new Member();
    }

    public string ObtainPassword() {

        if (LogMember != null && !LogMember.HasErrors)
        {
            return LogMember.GetPassword(LogMember.MemberName);
        }
        else { return ""; }

       }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Here is the c# code for LogIn window:

```
public partial class LogInWindow : Window
{
    public LogInWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LogInViewModel viewModelLog = (LogInViewModel)DataContext;
    }


    private void BttnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LogInViewModel logPassword = new LogInViewModel();
        string dbPassword = logPassword.ObtainPassword();
       
        if (dbPassword.Equals(Typepass.Password.ToString()))
        {
            MainWindow newMainWindow = new MainWindow();
            newMainWindow.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
            this.Close();
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Login failed. Please try again."); }
    }

    private void BttnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUserAdministrationUI.LogInWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:view_model="clr-namespace:WpfMyShop.ViewModel;assembly=WpfMyShop.ViewModel"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMyShopUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    

    Title="LogInWindow" Height="300" Width="250">
    
<Window.DataContext>
    <view_model:LogInViewModel></view_model:LogInViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="137" Margin="40,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164">
        <Label x:Name="Label1" Content="Membername"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MemberName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TextBoxAddMembername"  Height="27" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Label x:Name="Label3" Content=""/>
        <Label x:Name="Label2" Content="Member Password"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="Typepass" Height="27"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="30,210,0,30" >
        <Button Name="BttnLogin" Content="Log In" Width="80" Click="BttnLogin_Click"/>
        <Label Name="LabelBuffer" Content="    "/>
        <Button Name="BttnCancelLog" Content="Cancel" Width="80" Click="BttnCancel_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Do your other properties work OK?

Comment: Are you getting a binding error in the output window?

Comment: Is your DataContext being set properly?

Comment: The Binding should apparently be `{Binding Path=LogMember.MemberName, ...}`

Comment: Besides that, why do you create a new LogInViewModel in BttnLogin_Click. Shouldn't that method use the LogInViewModel instance in the DataContext?

Comment: @RobertHarvey There is only this property, because I will check for password directly on UI after obtaining password from DB. There is no binding error in the output. I will try to change the way of setting DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens I have already tried with your suggestion for Binding but it is still not working. I created a new LogInViewModel in BttnLogin_Click because I was getting a warning from IntelliSense that The viewModelLog does not exist in the current context (the instance created in Window_loaded). I will try to change the way of setting DataContext.